# How can we automatically update the designation of the employee after specific time through dynamics 365 project operation?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I want to update the designation of the employee after the specific time like Ramesh is an Associate consultant and after 1 year he will become a  consultant so i want to update his designation automatically after 1 year and i also want if i search in the consultant list after 1 year He is showing in this list.

Can we do this through resources area of project operation?

If anyone is having any idea about it please help me to this.

Comment: with little idea about project operation but enough knowledge about dynamics crm, I could think of Power Automate (cloud flow), run this flow on some schedule time or may it be some trigger and check some date may it be modified on or any of your custom date filed and it it is more than year update that record. There could be out of box way with project operation as mentioned I have little knowledge about it.

Comment: did you manged to get it solved?